# How Can I Add "New" Lazy Load Images To NewsPaper WP Theme?

Tags: jquery

I have NewsPaper WP theme. I added new widget for my theme, but new images doesn't support lazy load images. How can I add NewsPaper's lazy load system to them (with jQuery)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a question that should be asked of the NewsPaper official support streams.

Comment: If you know it, please help